# Understanding Openlayers MapServer configuration?

Tags: mapserver, openlayers-2

I need to implement functionality like this http://www.mpbhuabhilekh.nic.in/bhunakshaweb/.
I searched on net and found it can be done using Openlayers. I need simple and clear steps on how to to configure Openlayers, Mapserver or WMS.

I am working on windows 7 with xampp. I am using Openlayers2 with Mapserver in which we need map file to show the map. My map file name is `sample.map` and its location is `C:/ms4w/apps/mapserv-demo/sample.map`

Content of my sample.map file:

```
#Start of map file
MAP
    NAME "sample"
    STATUS ON
    SIZE 600 600
    EXTENT 388107.634400379 5203120.88405952 500896.339019834 5310243.30613897
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255

    #Start of web interface definition
    WEB
        #CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/ms4w/tmp/ms_error.txt"

        MINSCALE 1000
        MAXSCALE 1550000
        IMAGEPATH "C:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
        IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"

        METADATA
            WMS_TITLE "Sample Demo"
            WMS_ABSTRACT "This is a sample demo"
            WMS_ACCESSCONSTRAINTS "none"

            #change this value to match your setup
            WMS_ONLINERESOURCE "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?"

            WMS_SRS "EPSG:30134"
        END
    END #WEB

    #Start of layer definitions
    LAYER
        NAME 'global'
        TYPE RASTER
        STATUS DEFAULT

        CLASS
            NAME 'Digital Raster Graphic'
            KEYIMAGE graphics/drgs_keyimage.png
        END

        METADATA
            WMS_TITLE "Sample Demo"
            WMS_ABSTRACT "This is sample demo"
            WMS_ACCESSCONSTRAINTS "none"

            WMS_SRS "EPSG:30134"
        END
    END #LAYER

END #MAP
```

I am running only my map file to test if its working or not like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=C:/ms4w/apps/mapserv-demo/sample.map
```

But it's not working, it's showing the blank page.

Comment: If you remove  the ```#``` from this line ```#CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/ms4w/tmp/ms_error.txt"```  you should get an error message.  What does it say?  Also do you get a response from the WMS if you do a GetCapabilities  request like: ```http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&```